# SELECT with count average age using MONTHS_BETWEEN()

Tags: mysql, sql

For example. my table EMPLOYEE

```
//EMPLOYEE
E#      NAME      DOB
----------------------------
1       JOHN     13-10-1965
2       SITI     20-02-1968
3       ALI      31-03-1977
```

So my question is count each of their age, and then sum up together then divide by number of employees to count average ages of employees.

My currently statement.

```
SELECT DOB from employee where ..
// DIVIDE COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE
```

Comment: Why use `months_between` and why use a `where` clause?

Comment: as i no any idea to do it .

Comment: `select avg(datediff(curdate(), dob)) / 365 from employee`

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL?  `months_between()` is an Oracle function.

Comment: i done my question d. thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select sum(age)/count(*) as AVG from (SELECT Name,YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(dob) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(dob, 5)) as age 
  FROM EMPLOYEE )t
```

Comment: Load your data in sqlfiddle so I can test and able to give you query that run without any error

Comment: dont know why having some error input when for the date type
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2fb9a

Answer (score 0):

You can do as

```
SELECT 
avg(age) as  average_dob
from
(
  select
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,DOB,NOW()) AS age 
  from 
  Employee
)t;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e37c/10)**

Comment: it shown timestampdiff is invalid identifier for me

Comment: no it should not what is the date format you have in the table ?